# Return value for MySQL NULL result

Tags: mysql, null

I am working in MySQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT tar.ID, COUNT(tsr.StudentID) AS Students
FROM Teacher_ApplicationRecord tar
    LEFT JOIN Teacher_StudentRecord tsr ON sar.ID = tsr.TeacherID AND tsr.Session = 1 AND tsr.Year = 2017
WHERE tar.ApplicationYear = 2017
AND tar.Session1 = 1
```

This query returns no results. However if I take the `COUNT(tsr.StudentID)` out of the `SELECT` statement, it returns all the teacher ID's with `NULL` for the tsr table.

What I want is a query that returns all the teacher ID's and a count of the students assigned to that teacher, with 0 if the result is `NULL`.

I have tried `COALESCE(COUNT(tsr.StudentID), 0)` AND `IFNULL(COUNT(tsr.StudentID), 0)` with no success so far. Any other thoughts?

**UPDATE:**
The tsr table has 4 columns: TeacherID, StudentID, Year, Session. It has no records yet. It will be populated next year when students are assigned to teachers.

The tar table has a list of `TeacherID`'s in it with some other data, such as year and faculty.

I want my results to look like below:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| TeacherID | COUNT(StudentID)|
+-----------+-----------------+
|     1     |       0         |
+-----------+-----------------+
|     2     |       0         |
+-----------+-----------------+
etc.
```

As students are assigned to teachers, the COUNT(StudentID) numbers will go up. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 2**
The tar table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------------+
|TeacherID|ApplicationYear|
+---------+---------------+
|    1    |     2017      |
+---------+---------------+
|    2    |     2017      |
+---------+---------------+
|    3    |     2017      |
+---------+---------------+
```

It has other columns but they are not relevant to the question.

The tsr table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+----+-------+
|TeacherID|StudentID|Year|Session|
+---------+---------+----+-------+
|    1    |    10   |2017|   1   |
+---------+---------+----+-------+
|    1    |    11   |2017|   1   |
+---------+---------+----+-------+
|    2    |    12   |2017|   1   |
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and your expected output.  Your join or where conditions may not be doing what you think they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try joining the teacher table to the student table (in that order), and then using `GROUP BY` to count the number of students per teacher:

```
SELECT tsr.ID,
       COUNT(sar.ID) AS numOfStudents      -- count no matching students as zero
FROM Teacher_StudentRecord tsr
LEFT JOIN Student_ApplicationRecord sar
    ON tsr.TeacherID = sar.ID AND
       tsr.Session = 1 AND
       tsr.Year = 2017
GROUP BY tsr.ID
```

The usefulness of a `LEFT JOIN` here is the edge case where a teacher has no matching students.  In this case, the result set, before aggregation happens, would have a single record for that teacher, and the student ID value would be `NULL`, which be ignored by `COUNT`, resulting in a correct zero count.

Note that I removed the `WHERE` clause, whose intended logic is already contained in the `ON` clause.  This `WHERE` clause was throwing off your results by removing teacher records *before* they could even be aggregated.

**Update:**

Please try the following query to see if you get results:

```
SELECT tsr.ID,
       COUNT(sar.ID) AS numOfStudents
FROM Teacher_StudentRecord tsr
LEFT JOIN Student_ApplicationRecord sar
    ON tsr.TeacherID = sar.ID
GROUP BY tsr.ID
```

If this gives you no results, then no teachers are actually connected to any students, and your data has a problem.

Here is a **demo** using your sample data.  It works as expected:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim. Unfortunately it is still returning 0 results for me though.

Comment: @DylanHolloway Then there in no underlying data to be returned.  Please check your database.

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, Please see the update provided in the question.

Comment: @DylanHolloway The data you posted does nothing to help anyone solve your problem.  You showed the _style_ of output you want.  We need actual table data from both tables.  My guess is that your `ON` or `WHERE` clauses are responsible for no teachers joining to any students, hence an empty result set.

Comment: I tried your updated solution and it provided a list of teachers who had students assigned to them, but it still did not list the teachers who didn't have students assigned to them. I will update my question now to provide an example of the data I have.

Comment: @DylanHolloway Here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00a224/1) using your sample data, and it appears to be showing teachers who do not have any matching students.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for the query provided, however if you add `WHERE tsr.Year = 2017 AND tsr.Session = 1` it cuts out the third teacher.

Comment: @DylanHolloway I fixed it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00a224/3 ... get rid of that `WHERE` clause.